# VB NET: how to find a list of string which has max item count, from several list of string

Tags: vb.net, list

Could you please help me for this:

I have 5 lists of string, lets say A, B, C, D, and E:

```
A has 6 items
B has 5 items 
C has 9 items 
D has 2 items
E has 7 items
```

I need to sort or to find, "C" as the list which has max items.

I need to create tab in winform and on every tab I need to create datagridview programmatically. the maximum count in the list will be the maximum tab I need to create. And on every tab, there will be 1 item of every list member. Of course not all tab will have item from member which has small item count.

Previously what Ii did is iterate through table and datagrid to construct and solve the problem to avoid sorting the list cause I have no idea to find the max items on those lists.

UPDATE: Helped by Andrew

```
` Dim z As New List(Of List(Of String))

    Dim a As New List(Of String)
    a.Add("a1")
    a.Add("a2")
    a.Add("a3")

    Dim b As New List(Of String)
    b.Add("b1")
    b.Add("b2")
    b.Add("b3")
    b.Add("b4")
    b.Add("b5")


    Dim c As New List(Of String)
    c.Add("c1")
    c.Add("c2")
    c.Add("c3")
    c.Add("c3")

    z.Add(a)
    z.Add(b)
    z.Add(c)

    Dim maxItems = z.Max(Function(p) p.Count)
    MessageBox.Show(maxItems)`
```

Comment: What do you want to do with it once you have found it?

Comment: and what have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: From where do you get these list? Does it involve any database transactions

Comment: Sorry for not being clear..
I need to create tab in winform and on every tab i need to create datagridview programmatically.  the maximum count in the list will be the maximum tab i need to create. And on every tab, there will be 1 item of every list member. Of course not all tab will have item from member which has small item count.

Comment: @ssffzzxx if you _actually_ want help, then you'll need to show what you've tried on your own. this site is not a service for doing other peoples work.

Comment: @Aomine Thanks you for remind me.. actually i did a lot to solve this.. but previously what i did is iterate through table and datagrid to construct and solve the problem to avoid sorting the list cause i have no idea to find the max items on those lists.

Comment: @ssffzzxx that's fine if your solution is not the best or is not working, that's the whole point you're here right? so once again, please provide your current attempt not only to better illustrate your description but to show that you've actually spent time trying to come to a solution.

Comment: @ssffzzxx Hint: if you had `Dim z As New List(Of List(Of String)) From {A, B, C, D, E}`, could you find the [Max](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.7.2) [Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.count?view=netframework-4.7.2) of those inner Lists?

Comment: @Aomine So i create a public variable for each of list. Then i get first items for every list, and update the variable, once i take an element from each list, i fill the datagridview, and use first element of each list as parameter.

Comment: @ssffzzxx we're not making any progress here... what I am saying is **to show** your code.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks Andrew, let me try to sort it..

Comment: @Aomine Thanks friend, i will update once i figure it out

Comment: @ssffzzxx Following on from my previous comment, you can use a function in Max, like `Dim maxItems = z.Max(Function(p) p.Count)` (`p` is  a dummy variable, it could have almost any name).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks a lot.. i tried to do as you said. I can get the maximum list count for the lists . It is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is the length of the longest list...

```
Private A As New List(Of String) From {"Mathew", "Mark", "Luke", "John"}
Private B As New List(Of String) From {"Apples", "Oranges", "Pears"}
Private C As New List(Of String) From {"Haddock", "Salmon"}
Private D As New List(Of String) From {"Great Dane", "Poodle", "Bulldog", "Spaniel", "Golden Retriever"}

Private Sub GetMaxListLength()
    Dim E() As Integer = {A.Count, B.Count, C.Count, D.Count}
    Dim max = E.Max
    MessageBox.Show(max.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks .. i will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Both Mary answer and Andrew's work perfectly:

```
Dim z As New List(Of List(Of String))

    Dim a As New List(Of String)
    a.Add("a1")
    a.Add("a2")
    a.Add("a3")

    Dim b As New List(Of String)
    b.Add("b1")
    b.Add("b2")
    b.Add("b3")
    b.Add("b4")
    b.Add("b5")


    Dim c As New List(Of String)
    c.Add("c1")
    c.Add("c2")
    c.Add("c3")
    c.Add("c3")

    z.Add(a)
    z.Add(b)
    z.Add(c)

    Dim eb() As Integer = {a.Count, b.Count, c.Count}
    Dim max = eb.Max

    Dim maxItems = z.Max(Function(p) p.Count)
    MessageBox.Show(max)
```